# Слово "интерфейс" - правильно ли употребляется?

Tags: терминология, компьютеры

Словарь на грамота.ру даёт определение:

> ИНТЕРФЕЙС (от англ. interface – сопряжение, стык). Совокупность средств, обеспечивающих взаимодействие устройств ЭВМ и программ, а также взаимодействие их с человеком.

В некоем проекте, с которым я сталкиваюсь, тем не менее это слово упорно употребляется по отношению к одной или совокупности страниц веб-приложения. Например "Интерфейс "Справочник контрагентов", "Интерфейс "Журнал загрузки данных". Мне это сильно режет слух. В англоязычной документации, по крайней мере в отношении того средства разработки, о котором идёт речь, я тоже никогда не встречал употребление слова interface в этом случае. Только page или component. Не припомню и в русскоязычных текстах.

Правильно ли такое употребление?

Comment: Так названы вкладки программы или что-то другое?

Comment: Так написана документация. Например: "В интерфейсе должны отображаться ...", "Данный интерфейс предназначен для редактирования справочника дополнительных соглашений." и пр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе не вижу ничего некорректного. Веб-страница - тоже интерфейс. Причем любая. Другое дело, что это лишь одна её суть и обычно - не главная. Насколько актуально применение этого термина в конкретном случае зависит от того, что это за страница и чему вообще посвящена именно эта часть документации. Если все это подпадает под понятие "пользовательский интерфейс" - почему нет?

А это что, переводная документация? Или вы сравниваете с аналогами? Если первое, то появление термина действительно непонятно. А если второе, то аналог должен быть очень точным. Я за свою жизнь перечитал столько программной документации - при всем внешнем сходстве, она настолько по-разному пишется в том, что касается подобных частностей.

> "В интерфейсе должны отображаться ...", "Данный интерфейс
>   предназначен для редактирования справочника дополнительных
>   соглашений."

Это вполне доступная пониманию формулировка. Именно что пользовательский интерфейс. Во времена, когда о веб-приложениях - как и о самом термине "приложение" - и не слыхивали, в отношении программ (предназначенных, естественно, для выполнения на локальных компьютерах) подобный термин был весьма употребим. Нужен ли он у вас - не ознакомившись в деталях, сказать, естественно, не могу.

Comment: Нет, это самописная документация. В частности, я и сам вынужден писать именно этот термин, потому что он "официальный", но меня это раздражает. Спасибо за ответ.